# Location of Unknowns in Unstructured Mesh

Tags: pde, unstructured-mesh

I am currently learning a code which utilizes Scharfetter-Gummel discretization for unsteady drift-diffusion equations.  For this scheme, a 2D unstructured triangular mesh is used, with the unknowns located at the vertices of the mesh.  Cells are then constructed by perpendicular lines bisecting the chords between vertices and applying the finite volume formulation on the fluxes and internal processes in each cell.

This may simply be my inexperience with unstructured solvers, but I am wondering if there are equations/discretization schemes which would benefit from having the unknowns located at the centroid of each triangle, and the fluxes calculated over the chords.  For instance I know that the current code (and possible future replacements) also solve compressible laminar Navier-Stokes, the energy equation, Poisson's equation, and possible more accurate/coupled drift-diffusion models.  It would also be helpful for understanding if answers included whether it is extendable to 3D (I am assuming it would be).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dual mesh (the one formed by the perpendicular bisectors) is typically used as a FV mesh to allow the two-point flux approximation to be valid.  One requirement of the two-point flux approximation (in which the flux is based only upon the difference of the values at two neighboring cell centers) is that the segment connecting cell centroids is perpendicular to the edge the segment crosses.  If you draw two arbitrary triangles sharing an edge, you can see that this is typically not true for most simplex meshes.  However, if you then form the dual, you're left with a mesh for which this is true (your primal mesh's edges become the segments connecting cell centroids, and by construction are perpendicular to the new dual mesh's edges).

There are discretizations that can get around this issue and work on the primal mesh, in which triangles are now the cells.  These include mixed FE discretizations (the simplest is Raviart-Thomas finite elements) and Mimetic Finite Difference methods (nearly mathematically equivalent to methods known as nonlinear Finite Volume methods).

The second set of methods (MFD and variants) don't really "benefit" from working on the primal mesh, but their accuracy is not necessarily worse order, whereas standard FV methods can become 0th order as the above assumption is violated.

(All of the above, including forming the dual mesh from tetrahedrons instead of triangles, have natural extensions to 3D.)